# Scrollbar not restored on modal hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I have a modal and is opened by clicking on button.
When this modal is opened then i am getting 2 scroll bars,

1. first for Modal
2. second for html/body

I tried removing scrollbar as below:

```
if ($(".dialog-popup-open").length > 0) {
    $('html').css('overflow','hidden');
}
$(".closeButton").off("click").on("click", function () {
     $('html').css('overflow','scroll');
     //$('html').css('overflow','inherit');
}
```

Scroll bar is hiding perfectly but not restoring when modal is closed.
Any ideas please?

i tried both `scroll` and `inherit`

Comment: Are you using bootstrap modal?

Comment: why down vote here again :(   ... it is foundation modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this one:

```js
$("#openModal").click(function(){
  //code to open the overlay
  //....
  //....
  
  //add modalActive class to html tag
  $("html").addClass("modalActive");
  });

$(".closeButton").off("click").on("click", function () {
  
  //code to close the modal overlay
  //...
  //...
  
  
  //remove modalActive class from html
  $('html').removeClass("modalActive");

});
```

```css
.modalActive{
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Comment: i tried ur solution but removeClass is not working fine. Class is still there when i click closebutto

Comment: are you getting any JS error. anything getting logged in console

Comment: Nop.. that is weird... i m struggling though

Comment: `removeClass ` should work. Can you please add alert after `removeClass ' and check whether code is getting executed or not.

Comment: if found out the issue.. it is working :)   i was adding class when overlay is visible. And when overlay is closed, then ajax is fired which shows overlay again :)  .. i chnaged the event and now it is working.Also, not sure why people downvote without any expnanttion...

Comment: can u upvote ques.. as i hate people who downvote for no reason

Answer (score 0):

You need to give that to `body`:

```
$('body').css('overflow','auto');
```